# Prevent designer.cs from rebuild

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer, rebuild

I am using VS 2015 Pro. I have a form called `test`. The `test.designer.cs` file contains about 12k+ lines of code. It contains a lot of Telerik controls placed in several tabs (RadPageViewPage) and a lot of SplitContainer. Opening this form in design mode takes a few seconds, but that's not the issue.

Scenario problem:

1. Open two cards test.cs and test.cs [Design].
2. Add one line of code in test.cs. (`private Int32 x = 0`).
3. Perform build (Shift+F6)
4. Profit! ... not this time because build takes 20 secound. :(

If you execute the same but without opening test.cs [Design], the build is done in 1 second.

1. Why VS rebuilds designer.cs file if I had not done any change in design mode?
2. How to prevent this from happening?
3. What are the best practices for such a large form containing a large amount of controls?

**Edit 1:**
So the assumption that designer.cs is rebuilt is wrong.
The problem is something else.
I started VS using devenv.exe /log.
Below are some errors that may be related to my problem:

```
483  Begin package load [Toolbox Controls Installer Package] {2C298B35-07DA-45F1-96A3-BE55D91C8D7A}  VisualStudio 2015/08/27 08:59:05.832
484  End package load [Toolbox Controls Installer Package] {2C298B35-07DA-45F1-96A3-BE55D91C8D7A}  VisualStudio 2015/08/27 08:59:05.833 
485 ERROR Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.866 
486 ERROR Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.867 
487 ERROR Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.867 
488 ERROR Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.867 
489 ERROR Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.867 
490 ERROR Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.867 
491 ERROR Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.867 
492 ERROR Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.867 
493 ERROR Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.867 
494 ERROR Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.867 
495 ERROR Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.867 
496 ERROR Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.868 
497 ERROR Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.868 
498 ERROR Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.868 
499 ERROR Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.868 
500 ERROR Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.868 
501 ERROR Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.868 
502 ERROR Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.868 
503 ERROR Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.868 
504 ERROR Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.868 
505 ERROR Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.868 
506 ERROR Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.868 
507 ERROR Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.868 
508 ERROR Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.868 
509 ERROR Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.869 
510 ERROR Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.869 
511 ERROR Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.869 
512 ERROR Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.869 
513 ERROR Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.869 
514 ERROR Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.869 
515 ERROR Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.869 
516 ERROR Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.870 
517 ERROR Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.870 
518 ERROR Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.870 
519 ERROR Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.870 
520 ERROR Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.870 
521 ERROR Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.870 
522 ERROR Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.870 
523 ERROR Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.870 
524 ERROR Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.870 
525 ERROR Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.870 
526 ERROR Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.871 
527 ERROR Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.871 
528 ERROR Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.871 
529 ERROR Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.871 
530 ERROR Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.871 
531 ERROR Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.871 
532 ERROR Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.871 
533 ERROR Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.871 
534 ERROR Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.871 
535 ERROR Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.871 
536 ERROR Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.871 
537 ERROR Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.871 
538 ERROR Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.871 
539 ERROR Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.871 
540 ERROR Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.871 
541 ERROR Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.872 
542 ERROR Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.872 
543 ERROR Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.872 
544 ERROR Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.872 
545 ERROR Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.872 
546 ERROR Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.872 
547 ERROR Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.872 
548 ERROR Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2015/08/27 08:59:05.872 
549  Done loading new toolbox content, total time = 125 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the .cs file will trigger a regeneration of the designer file, no way around that. I would recommend partialling your class again and putting frequently-modified code in a separate code file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Making changes in *Form.cs* in code view, **never** changes *Form.Designer.cs* in normal situations. It doesn't depend on having Designer view open or close.
   *Form.cs* has 2 views, Code view and Designer view. Only making changes in Designer view will cause to regeneration of *Form.Designer.cs* even both views were open.
2. Don't change *Form.Designer.cs* manually or Don't change Designer view. Some 3rd party components make change in designer generated codes each time the form shown in Designer view and makes it to show a * in its VS tab.
3. Putting controls in a UserControl and Put the UserControl on your form may be a workaround. If you provide suitable methods and properties for UserControl you don't need to open UserControl Designer and then the code of designer will never generate again.

I simply arranged a test with a form containing hundreds of standard windows forms controls. The designer file was over 14000 lines of code. I tested opening and changing files with states you described (and some other states).

- The Form.Designer.cs only generated if some change was made in in Designer view.
- Cost of working in Designer view and making changes and therefore regenaration of Form.Designer.cs was high.
- Cost of building of application was the same in each state (if you save all files first).

Comment: In my case, do not touch the Designer. Perhaps in the past I changed something manually in the designer.cs file . Could this lead to the current situation? However, from what I know, VS creates a completely new designer.cs file if build is needed.

Comment: After first test variable declaration is still there. So the assumption that designer.cs is rebuilt is wrong. I moved a control in design view and after saving the declaration disappeared. The second test: * does not appear. So what is the cause of VS freeze for 10-15 seconds if the design view is open.